# Functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am following the following tutorial to deploy fulfillment on [Google Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app) (it's for setting up firebase, at this point). However, when I do: 
    firebase deploy --only functions
in my cmd, I get an error: 
    Functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1.
At first, I modified $RESOURCE_DIR to %RESOURCE_DIR% in my firebase.json since I'm using Windows. This reduced the number of errors I had drastically, but I still have the aforementioned one. Any ideas? The output error is shown here: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikWAM.png)